# Why did R"G admit that he acted inHalachicly?

Tags: bava-metzia

After the incident of Tanuro Shel Akhnai (B"M 59), G-d tried to threaten/punish R"G by wrecking his ship, probably realizing that he [somehow] sinned. His response was that he acted out of "שלא ירבו מחלוקות בישראל" (to minimize/prevent future arguments).

As he didn't stick to a simple Halachic answer (like "I was following Your Halacha of אחרי רבים or לא בשמים היא") can we deduce that he admitted to acting unHalachicly (sort of עת לעשות לה' הפרו תורתך - time to do for Hashem, time to override Your Torah)?

Answer (score 2):

Wrecking  the ship is not for arguing with R' Eliezer, it's for putting him in *Cherem* (outcast him).